# Database years and tables

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have a database with 3 tables `ArtNr`, `Year` and `Price`

```
`select * from database`
```

will give something like this

```
ArtNr     - Year - Price
------------------------    
601230001 - 2011 - 100
601230001 - 2012 - 110
601230001 - 2013 - 105
604560001 - 2012 - 250
604560001 - 2013 - 225
```

How can I get a result like

```
ArtNr     - 2011 - 2012 - 2013
------------------------------    
601230001 -  100 -  110 -  105
604560001 - NULL -  250 -  225
```

Comment: Such a transormation is called a `Pivot table`. How to achieve this strongly depends on your database system. Which are you using?

Comment: Hi, I use MS SQL-server 2008

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  ArtNr,
        MIN(CASE WHEN Year = 2011 THEN Price END) Year2011,
        MIN(CASE WHEN Year = 2012 THEN Price END) Year2012,
        MIN(CASE WHEN Year = 2013 THEN Price END) Year2013
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ArtNr
```

Comment: Yes, this should work as long as there is exactly one row for each combination of `ArtNr` and `Year`.

Comment: If I use a select like this I will have to change the querie every year... I was more looking for a query for the next coming years :D

Comment: @user3541595 Then do a quick search for "sql-server dynamic pivot" here and you'll get hundreds of answers dealing with this

Comment: I didn't know Pivot so this Noob will do some reading about Pivot

Answer (score 0):

A pivot table (in access/excel known as a 'crosstab') is needed here. We could hard code a select with some case statements to cover a fixed number of years, but that solution would have to be revisited each time a year was added or removed. @Lamak has such a solution below.

Or, if I had the ability to (and I never do), I would switch database engines. Here are three DB engines that provide tools for creating pivot tables:

- Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html
- Postgres: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html
- SQL Server: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx